# Can't read from MS Access database in C#

Tags: c#

This is my code, I has put this function in my case there, why can I still not  retrieve any data from my MS Access database? Is it the database problem? Or because my MS Access is version 2013 which is a pirated version?

```
public void display(event_detail e)
{
    string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string connstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + @"\GameMuseumManagementSystem.mdb";

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring); //Create connection
    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from Event  WHERE Event_Title ='" + PassName + "'", conn); //Create command

    cmd.Connection = conn; //command connect to database

    OleDbDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        e.notxt.Text = (myReader["Event_No"].ToString());
        //e.notxt.ReadOnly = true;
        e.titletxt.Text = (myReader["Event_Name"].ToString());
        //e.titletxt.ReadOnly = true;
        e.datedetail.Text = (myReader["Event_Date"].ToString());
        //e.datedetail.ReadOnly = true;
        e.detailtxt.Text = (myReader["Event_detail"].ToString());
        //e.detailtxt.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error,just msg cant display on textbox @LJ

Comment: When you debug the code, are you getting inside the while loop? Also are you sure that there is data in the table that you are pinging?

Comment: yes @L J,the textbox doesnot retrieve any data from my microsoft access and the textbook still blinking

Comment: Did you try removing the where clause?

Comment: Please see [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements), in particular you want to use parameters and use `using` blocks around your connection so it is closed when you are done with it.

Comment: What's the value of PassName?  Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.  You should use an `if (myReader.Read())` instead since you are only expecting one row.  This is a debugging issue, so put a stop line at the top, run your code, and then step through the code line by line and check the values.

Comment: That said you need to debug your code and your query. Copy/Paste your query into MS Access and run it and see what comes back. If there is no data because your where clause is too restrictive that would answer your question.

Comment: my microsoft access is pirated version